# Is eating an apple from a tree planted right next to a granddad's tomb not permitted?

Tags: impermanence

Suppose A's granddad died many years ago and was buried in the back yard.

Right next to his tomb, grows a very fruitful apple tree. There are many delicious apples on that tree.

Is it ok to eat these apples?

There is a very high chance, that the tree obtained energy from the tomb. When the granddad's corpse decayed, it released a lot of biological substances that are good for the tree.

Comment: Off topic? Or is there some connection to Buddhist practice that I am missing here?

Comment: In Buddism, is it allowed?

Comment: @Tom, did you hear or read somewhere that this act was not permitted? If we have more context surrounding your question, we can provide better answers. Then we can also edit the question so it helps other people with the same question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.                   It is ok.

Comment: But then A eats his granddad???

Comment: No. Just an apple

Comment: These bodies are all made from the same material that is being used and reused many times over. The matter is not your granddad. What matters is form, configuration, information, causation, relationships.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of reference I'm on my phone! I'll get back to you @tom in a while :)